# How to convert negative numbers into bit string?

Tags: integer, negative-number, zk-snark, circom, circomlib

If you want to bitlfy an integer in circom, you have to you use the `Num2bits()` from the circomlib library (an equivalent of libstdc++ for circom) such as :

```
inp = Num2bits(120);
inp.in = (3);

hash = Poseidon2(1);
has.in[0] = inp.out;
```

But what if I want to hash 1-2<sup>252</sup> or -5 ? Even if the last bits are still 0 for the first case, unless I’m wrong, `Num2bits()` can’t be used in those case…

Comment: At that point, I do no longer understand the difference of purposes between `Num2bits()` and `Num2bits_strict()`. But after all, the main library of circom that is circomlib is mostly undocumented.